# Does Milo supports Publish/Subscribe?

Tags: publish, subscribe, opc-ua, milo

Does Milo supports Publish/Subscribe?  I didn't saw relevant description in milo's project websit. I have searched Publish/Subscribe API in source code, but I'm not sure whether Milo support Publish/Subscribe. ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It supports the client/server subscription mechanism, but it does not support PubSub as defined by [OPC UA Part 14](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part14/v105/docs/).